# Detecting capturing moves that pawns can make, in both directions

Tags: java, chess

I have this function that contains two similar `if` statements that is kind of hard to re-factor.

I am saying this because these two share a significant portion of duplicated code, but because of the part where it differs slightly, like `board[startX + 1][startY - 1]` and `board[startX - 1][startY - 1]`, I find it difficult to re-factor it efficiently.

In other words, I can surely re-factor this by creating another function that contains the common parts, but I am afraid of creating a few more `if` blocks inside that function and making the code dirtier.

Any advice for refactoring this kind of code?

```
public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {

    //If the Pawn belong to the Upper Team (Faces downward)
    if(board[startX][startY] != null && board[startX][startY].getTeam() == Player.UP) {
        //If a Piece exists on a diagonally adjacent tile, return true
        if(startX - endX == -1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
            if( (board[startX + 1][startY - 1] != null && board[startX + 1][startY - 1].getTeam() != Player.UP) || 
                    (board[startX + 1][startY + 1] != null && board[startX + 1][startY + 1].getTeam() != Player.UP)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } 

    if(board[startX][startY] != null && board[startX][startY].getTeam() == Player.DOWN) { 
        //If the Pawn belongs to the Down Team (Faces upward)

        if(startX - endX == 1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
            //If a Piece exists on a diagonally adjacent tile, return true
            if( (board[startX - 1][startY - 1] != null && board[startX - 1][startY - 1].getTeam() != Player.DOWN) || 
                    (board[startX - 1][startY + 1] != null && board[startX - 1][startY + 1].getTeam() != Player.DOWN)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Comment: You would probably be better off doing a broader restructuring of your chess engine. I suggest that you post more of your code so that we may advise you better.

Comment: First, you need to document what the function does and what the input values mean.  For example, I am confused as to why you check two squares for enemy pieces and not just the one square denoted by `(endX, endY)`.  What does returning true from the function mean?

Comment: I would add an integer `direction` which is `-1` or `+1` based on the player..

Answer (score 1):

> In other words, I can surely re-factor this by creating another function that contains the common parts, but I am afraid of creating a few more if blocks inside that function and making the code dirtier.

Au contraire. If your refactoring is *increasing* the code complexity, you're not doing it right.

The refactoring I did in this answer has reduced maximum nesting to a *single* level.

Maybe some quick-fire observations about why your code was so complex:

- You were pushing all your calculations into your array index, which caused you to have to repeat the same `value+1` and `value-1` statements over and over.
- As you already acknowledged, you had copy/pasted code and only made minor alterations (turning a `+1` into a `-1` due to the different player teams).
- Your variables names weren't really all that clear, nor clearly used. Even after having refactored it, I still have no clue what `endX` and `endY` were used for.

---

There are two "types" of refactoring:

- Simplifying code by changing it while not making any **functional** difference.

A simple example would be seeing `if(myBool == true)` and changing it to `if(myBool)`. It makes no functional difference, and therefore can be safely refactored.

- Revisiting the code and redesigning it, so you can optimize it with knowledge you have now (but didn't have at the time).

This often happens when a problem is complex at the beginning, but after developing a solution, it looks so much easier in hindsight.

We're going to be doing the second type of refactoring here. Which means we'll start from scratch and build the requirements as they come.

---

**Assumptions**:

- Arrays are 0-indexed (it's been a while since I did Java, I think that's the case?)
- We're using screen coordinates:

[image]

---

**Method signature**

We want:

- A boolean that tells us whether the pawn *can* capture an enemy.

We need to supply:

- The specific pawn
- Access to the game board for retrieving information.

Your code:

```
public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY)
```

I've been looking at it for a while, and I genuinely have no idea why you are supplying `endX` and `endY`. My suggestion:

```
public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int pawnX, int pawnY)
```

---

**1 - Input validation**

Let's store the pawn in its own variable, for ease of use:

```
Piece pawn = board[pawnX][pawnY];
```

Does the referenced position actually contain a pawn? As it stands, you're only really checking for null, so I'll do the same:

```
if (pawn == null)
    return false;
```

Notice that I inverted the logic. If the pawn *does not* exist, then we immediately return false. This helps reduce nesting, and you won't need to indent the subsequent code.

---

**2 - Defining the *possible* capture regions**

To help you simplify this, let's look at the row calculation and the column calculation separately:

**Columns** are easy: given that a pawn is standing in column X, the capture regions can be found in columns **X-1** and **X+1**.
Importantly, this is true for both the UP and DOWN players!

```
int captureColumnLeft = pawnX - 1;
int captureColumnRight = pawnX + 1;
```

*When the pawn is on column 0 or 7, it will only have one capture region. But we'll get to that later.*

**Rows**, however, are a bit more complex. This is the first time we need to observe the *team* that this pawn belongs to. Given that a pawn is standing on row Y, its capture regions are found in row **Y+1** for the UP player, but in row **Y-1** for the DOWN player.

```
int captureRow;

if(pawn.getTeam() == Player.UP)
    captureRow = pawnY + 1;
else
    captureRow = pawnY - 1;
```

*We don't need to exclude fringe cases. A pawn can never be at the end of the board (for either player), since it would then turn into another piece.*

Now we've very easily defined a given pawn's capture regions:

```
Piece captureRegionLeft = board[captureColumnLeft][captureRow];
Piece captureRegionRight = board[captureColumnRight][captureRow];
```

The next step is checking to see if there is a capturable piece on any of the capture regions. As the logic is exactly the same for both regions, we'll put this in a new method.

Before we get to that, let's close our current method:

```
return CanCaptureAt(captureRegionLeft, pawn) 
       || CanCaptureAt(captureRegionRight, pawn);
```

---

**3 - Checking if a possible capture region contains a capturable piece**

```
public boolean CanCaptureAt(Piece captureRegion, Piece pawn)
{

    // ...

}
```

The logic isn't all that hard:

- If there is no piece in the capture region, we cannot capture anything in that region.

  `if(captureRegion == null)` 
      `return false;`
- If there is a piece in the capture region, it must be of the opposing team. In other words, a piece is capturable if the teams are different:

  `return captureRegion.getTeam() != pawn.getTeam();`

---

**Combined:**

```
public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int pawnX, int pawnY)
{
    Piece pawn = board[pawnX][pawnY];

    if (pawn == null)
        return false;

    int captureColumnLeft = pawnX - 1;
    int captureColumnRight = pawnX + 1;

    int captureRow;

    if(pawn.getTeam() == Player.UP)
        captureRow = pawnY + 1;
    else
        captureRow = pawnY - 1;

    Piece captureRegionLeft = board[captureColumnLeft][captureRow];
    Piece captureRegionRight = board[captureColumnRight][captureRow];

    return CanCaptureAt(captureRegionLeft, pawn) 
        || CanCaptureAt(captureRegionRight, pawn);
}

public boolean CanCaptureAt(Piece captureRegion, Piece pawn)
{    
    if(captureRegion == null) 
        return false;

    return captureRegion.getTeam() != pawn.getTeam();    
}
```

---

**Additionally**

I said we still needed to exclude two fringe cases: if the pawn is on the leftmost column, it doesn't have a left capture region; and when it is on the rightmost column, it's doesn't have a right capture region.

This can be achieved by slightly reshuffling the code:

```
public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int pawnX, int pawnY)
{
    Piece pawn = board[pawnX][pawnY];

    if (pawn == null)
        return false;

    int captureRow;

    if(pawn.getTeam() == Player.UP)
        captureRow = pawnY + 1;
    else
        captureRow = pawnY - 1;

    if(pawnX > 0) // == NOT in the leftmost column
    {
        int captureColumnLeft = pawnX - 1;
        Piece captureRegionLeft = board[captureColumnLeft][captureRow];

        if(CanCaptureAt(captureRegionLeft, pawn)) 
            return true;
    }

    if(pawnX < 7) // == NOT in the rightmost column
    {
        int captureColumnRight = pawnX + 1;
        Piece captureRegionRight = board[captureColumnRight][captureRow];

        if(CanCaptureAt(captureRegionRight, pawn)) 
            return true;
    }

    //Neither caption region registered a hit,
    //Therefore we cannot capture anything
    return false;
}
```

---

**Footnotes**

- There is currently no check to see if the provided X/Y values are within the bounds of the board.
- There is currently no check to see if the `Piece` at the provided X/Y coordinates is actually a pawn.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

I looked at the two innermost if statements and noted the differences:

1. the operator in startX index (adding and substracting 1)
2. the team compared against - it is the opposite team of `board[startX][startY]`

so I took these differences as arguments to the new method `checkDiagonallyAdjacentTile()` which contains the similar part of the if statement with the arguments specified in the correct places.

I also beautified the code a little: no need for parenthesis in `&&` condition
and broke down the two outer if statements, allowing for an `else` construct.

The end result is below

```
public boolean checkDiagonallyAdjacentTile(Piece[][] board, int addToStartX, Player playerTeam) {
    // if a Piece of opposite team exists on a diagonally adjacent tile, return true
    if (board[startX + addToStartX][startY - 1] != null && board[startX + addToStartX][startY - 1].getTeam() != playerTeam || 
        board[startX + addToStartX][startY + 1] != null && board[startX + addToStartX][startY + 1].getTeam() != playerTeam) {
           return true;
    }
    return false;
}


public boolean hasCapturableEnemy(Piece[][] board, int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY) {

    boolean hasCapturableEnemy = false;

    // if the Pawn belong to the Upper Team (Faces downward)
    if (board[startX][startY] != null) {
        if (board[startX][startY].getTeam() == Player.UP) {
            if (startX - endX == -1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
                hasCapturableEnemy = checkDiagonallyAdjacentTile(board, 1, board[startX][startY].getTeam());
            }
        } else {
            if (startX - endX == 1 && Math.abs(startY - endY) == 1) {
                hasCapturableEnemy = checkDiagonallyAdjacentTile(board, -1, board[startX][startY].getTeam());
            }
        }
    }

    return hasCapturableEnemy;
}
```